# Different PDF output for Windows and Linux using Phantomjs 1.9

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

I am trying to convert a `html` page to PDF using `Phantomjs 1.9`.

My html looks like:

```
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" >
    <div id="myDiv" style="width:1024px; height:768px; margin:0px; border:none">
             content
       </div>   
</body>
```

in `rasterize.js` I have:

```
page.viewportSize = {width: '1026px', height: '768px'};
page.paperSize = { width: '1026px', height: '768px', border:'0px'};
```

When generating the PDF on Windows I get the full content of `div id="myDiv"` rendered correctly on 1 page, no borders.

When I run the same code on Linux the content of the `div` is cropped horizontally and stretches on 2 pages.

Can you please help me understand why won't the same settings work on Linux and how can I fix the issue.

Thank you

Comment: For Linux I had to set page.zoomFactor = 0.5 in order to work

Answer (score 0):

For Linux I had to set page.zoomFactor = 0.5 in order to work

Comment: page.zoomFactor doesn't work in phantomjs 2.1.1 on Linux. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12685

Answer (score 0):

PhanthomJS uses different virtual dpi on different OSes.
I've just defined custom sheet size in millimeters and it helped.
I suppose that pre-defined sheet sizes are defined in pixels.